# Quick to delete

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

This question got deleted 4 hours only after it was put on hold. Why (Roomba or human decision?)? I find it a bit fast as it doesn't give other people a chance to express their opinions.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see, this was deleted by the Community ♦ User. This occurred because it was deemed a `dead question` by SE-wide policy. This process applies when a question is more than 30 days old and ...

- has −1 or lower score,
- has no answers, and
- is not locked.

To my understanding*, it actually had nothing to do with the fact that it was put on hold, nor did it have anything to do with a “quick” decision by a moderator or anyone else. It was part of a scheduled, automated process that occurred when the question turned 30 days old. Please see [this explanation of the process and the reasoning behind it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/272257) on Meta.SE if you would like further information.

<sub>*Anyone should feel free to correct me if I’m wrong about this.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, I mistakenly thought comments were preventing Roomba from cleaning, but it doesn't for -1 questions.